# Regex to block all special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for an name field and block all special characters

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69mqhzq6/

However, my code seems to ignore it. Could someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
var blockSpecialRegex = new RegExp("~`!@#$%^&()_={}\[\]\:;,.\/<>/-+/?");
  var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  console.log(key)
  if(blockSpecialRegex.test(key) || $.isNumeric(key)){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  });
```

Comment: Use `var blockSpecialRegex = /[~\`!@#$%^&()_={}[\]:;,.<>+\/?-]/;`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Any idea why passing it in `new RegExp` fails?

Comment: Yes, you did not define a character class, just enumerated the symbols.

Comment: @ultimatecoder : see my answer why passing it in `new RegExp` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just enumerated the special chars without creating a character class defined with the help of `[...]`.

I suggest using a regex literal with a character class matching any of the symbols defined in it:

```
var blockSpecialRegex = /[~`!@#$%^&()_={}[\]:;,.<>+\/?-]/;
```

Note that the `-` should be at the start/end of the character class to denote a literal `-` symbol. The `]` inside must be escaped, but `[` does not have to be escaped. `/` must be escaped because it is a regex delimiter symbol.

JS code:

```js
$('input').on('keypress', function (e) {
var blockSpecialRegex = /[~`!@#$%^&()_={}[\]:;,.<>+\/?-]/;
  var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  console.log(key)
  if(blockSpecialRegex.test(key) || $.isNumeric(key)){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regex to allow only alphabets,numbers and spaces(if required)
^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$

Comment: You are right. I was using `/^[A-z]/` earlier but it allowed some special characters, so I completely abandoned it.. but your modification seems simpler.

Comment: @ultimatecoder: That is most probably because [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970). Also, `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$` won't allow `я`, `ź`, etc. That seems to be out of scope of the current question.

Answer (score 0):

When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.

So you need to do this:

```
var blockSpecialRegex = new RegExp("[~`!@#$%^&()_={}\\[\\]\\:;,\\.\\/<>\\\\*\\-+\\?]");
```

[See RegExp - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)